# Laravel, default value ignore with variable

Tags: php, forms, laravel

// EDIT

It was a problem in my controller and it specific in my project. My bad, sorry

// END EDIT

I'm pretty lost with something and I need help, this project was not done by me, I just need to do a quick fix.

I have a select in a form :

```
 {{ Form::label('option', 'Type de contrat') }}
 {{ Form::select('option[]', $contracts->lists('option', 'id')->toArray(), old('option')[0], ['class' => 'form-control selectpicker']) }}
```

When my form is not fill correctly, I'm redirect to the form page and I want the select have the previous value. It should be work with the "old".

But it select the first value.
So I  tried `var_dump(old('option')[0])` which return me `"16"` (string variable) who is the id of the previous selected and the value of the option who need to be selected.

But if I try (replace the variable by hardcoded value):

```
{{ Form::label('option', 'Type de contrat') }}
{{ Form::select('option[]', $contracts->lists('option', 'id')->toArray(), 16, ['class' => 'form-control selectpicker']) }}
```

It's work and I don't understand why ...

I try :

```
(int)old('option')[0]
```

But doesn't work

Laravel 5.2

Why it's work with a hardcoded int but now with a variable who return a int number ?

Select generate :

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" name="option[]" tabindex="-98">

  <option value="13">CDD</option><option value="14">CDI</option>
  <option value="15">Stage</option>
  <option value="16">Apprentissage</option>
  <option value="17">Freelance</option>

 </select>
```

Comment: Doesnt work, was the previous value and what I need to fix because they are more select with name "option[]" so it's return a array with "old"

Comment: This should work by default. Could you please show what HTML `Form::select` is generating?

Comment: Question edited @mrHooty

Comment: Why do you need to use `option[]`?  Do you have more than 1 `<select>` in your form?

Comment: @Hash Yeah i have more than one, was done like this before by another pepole and change the logic take to much time.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not a multi-select, you don't need the `[]` in the name of the input,

You need to use it like this:

```
 {{ Form::select('option', $contracts->lists('option', 'id')->toArray(), old('option'), ['class' => 'form-control selectpicker']) }}
```

Comment: Edited again. That's how I do it every day

Comment: There are another selection with the name "option[]" so i need to keep it. My question is : Why it's work with a hardcoded int but now with a variable who return a int number ?

Comment: Try doing this in your Form select label `{{ Form::label('option', 'Type de contrat' . old('option.0') }} and check if it shows `16` also

Comment: It return the good value but the select is alaways in the first option

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one, then you can try it:

**view**

```
@for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++)
  <input type="hidden" name="count_select[]">
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="option{$i}" tabindex="-98">

  <option value="13"{{ (old("option{$i}") == 13) ? ' selected' : '' }}>CDD</option>
  <option value="14"{{ (old("option{$i}") == 14) ? ' selected' : '' }}>CDI</option>
  <option value="15"{{ (old("option{$i}") == 15) ? ' selected' : '' }}>Stage</option>
  <option value="16"{{ (old("option{$i}") == 16) ? ' selected' : '' }}>Apprentissage</option>
  <option value="17"{{ (old("option{$i}") == 17) ? ' selected' : '' }}>Freelance</option>

 </select>
@endfor
```

**controller**

```
$count_select = $request->input('count_select');

if(count($count_select) > 0){
   for($a = 1; $a <= count($count_select); $a++){
      $this->validate($request, [
        "option{$a}" => 'required'
      ]);
   }
}
```

Comment: My question is Why it's work with a hardcoded int but now with a variable who return a int number ?
I don't want to change the logic if it's just a type problem or something like that, it work with hardcoded but not with variable who have exactly the same value

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine ooh, I got it. Your question seems to be a little confusing. However, do you get the exact value if you use variable?  Can you try to inspect element for the value?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not native in English so it's explain why it's confusing.
Yeah i get the correct value. It's just a string instead of int and if I convert it with "(int)" it return me the correct value in int format but the select always chose the first option

Comment: Try to use `(int)$variable`. Convert all the value of your select to `(int)` as well.

Comment: Already do it, correct value in int format if I var_dump but the select chose first option

Comment: Use `var_dump((int)old('option')[0])`

Comment: Try to just convert all with `(int)`.

Comment: I got it now, Because you're selecting the first item in the array which is `[0]`

Comment: Try to remove `[0]`

Comment: No, if I remove the "[0]" it return me an array, and with the "(int)" it's give me the correct value in this case 16 (integer) but the select doesn't care and select first option. "old('option')[0]" return me the value I need, my problem is why the slect doesn't select it

Comment: Wait, if with `(int)` is not working, then why are putting it?  why not in your controller instead?  Because if the value that reads by PHP is a string, then it will never be return the exact value with `(int)`.

Comment: Okay I just see it's all my fault, I was a problem in the controller (I doesn't know something special was done in it because it was not me who do it). It's all my bad sorry. Thanks for your time